# Error while Installing Eclipse on a Linux Hosted Server - JVM Terminated Exit Code =2

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I am new to Java and trying to install Eclipse BIRT on a hosted linux server. I have executed the below commands using putty.

Step 1. Downloaded and extracted eclipse-reporting-neon-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz file to /home/xxone/eclipse in cpanel.

Step2. Downloaded jdk-8u241-linux-i586.tar.gz and extracted into /home/xxone/jdk1.8.0_241/

Step 3: [Set the Java home and path varaibles][1]

export JAVA_HOME=/home/xxone/jdk1.8.0_241/
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Step 4: set -vm arguments in eclipse.ini as below

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/home/xxone/jdk1.8.0_241/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Step 5: when i try to run the eclipse file through putty, I am getting the below error.

---

```
[root@cloud eclipse]# ./eclipse
Eclipse:
GTK+ Version Check
Eclipse:
JVM terminated. Exit code=2
/home/xxone/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /home/xxone/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v2016                                                                             0318-1642.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /home/xxone/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.0.v2016060                                                                             6-1100/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/xxone/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/xxone/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher                                                                             .gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444/eclipse_1617.so
-startup /home/xxone/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v                                                                             20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 40001
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
-vm /home/xxone/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /home/xxone/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v2016                                                                             0318-1642.jar
```

---

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What display is Eclipse supposed to show up on, and which steps made that possible?

Comment: I was expecting eclipse to load up GUI with the list of tools where in i can select Report Developer and then start working on it.